# Iterating through values of one column to get descriptive statistics for another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I'm trying to get descriptive statistics for a column of data (the `tb` column which is a list of numbers) for every individual (i.e., each `ID`). Normally, I'd use a `for i in range(len(list))` statement but since the `ID` is not a number I'm unsure of how to do that. Any tips would be helpful! The code included below gets me descriptive statistics for the entire `tb` column, instead of for `tb` data for each individual in the `ID` list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("SurgeryTpref.csv")) #importing data

df.columns = ['date', 'time', 'tb', 'ID','before_after'] #column headers
df.to_numpy()
```

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the data in with 
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')

# data
,date,time,tb,ID,before_after
0,6/29/20,4:15:33 PM,37.1,SR10,after
1,6/29/20,4:17:33 PM,38.1,SR10,after
2,6/29/20,4:19:33 PM,37.8,SR10,after
3,6/29/20,4:21:33 PM,37.5,SR10,after
4,6/29/20,4:23:33 PM,38.1,SR10,after
5,6/29/20,4:25:33 PM,38.5,SR10,after
6,6/29/20,4:27:33 PM,38.6,SR10,after
7,6/29/20,4:29:33 PM,37.6,SR10,after
8,6/29/20,4:31:33 PM,35.5,SR10,after
9,6/29/20,4:33:33 PM,34.7,SR10,after


summary=[]    
for individual in (ID):
    vals= df['tb'].describe()
    summary.append(vals)
print(summary)
```

Comment: Thank you @TrentonMcKinney. I've tried to provide a minimal reproducible example by following the directions in the other stack overflow post. Please let me know if you have more suggestions/tips for how I can improve the question. Thank you -Lauren

Comment: You are generating statistics on the same array on every iteration... if you select only one row, what kind of statistic would you expect from a float `37.1`?

Comment: Each ```ID``` has ~60 rows of ```tb``` data in the df. I don't think I understand your comment. The code I have above doesn't select only one row of data, right?

Comment: I didn't see the actual ID column after tb... try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33576648/6692898)

Comment: `df.groupby('ID').describe()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get columns describe from group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579148/get-columns-describe-from-group-by)

Comment: Hi Trenton, yes that answers my question. Thanks for the help!